# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.hadoop.mapred.MongoInputFormat when running Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I'm creating a flink system in Java to read and write into MongoDB. I'm using mongo-hadoop-core version 1.3.2 and Apache flink 1.6 in JDK 1.8.0_181.

When I run the source in Eclipse, everything runs successfully, but when I'm using the flink command to run a JAR file, I always get this error.

here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
<artifactId>test-mongodb-2</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305</exclude>
                                <exclude>org.slf4j:*</exclude>
                                <exclude>log4j:*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <!-- Do not copy the signatures in the META-INF folder.
                                Otherwise, this might cause SecurityExceptions when using the JAR. -->
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>my.programs.main.clazz</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-streaming-java_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
      <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
      <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.mongo-hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
        <artifactId>flink-hadoop-compatibility_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

but after i change mongo-hadoop-core version into 1.3.2, it gives different error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not look up the main(String[]) method from the class MongoDBExample: org/apache/flink/api/java/hadoop/mapred/HadoopInputFormat
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.hasMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:499)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.<init>(PackagedProgram.java:218)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.<init>(PackagedProgram.java:128)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.buildProgram(CliFrontend.java:856)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:206)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1044)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$11(CliFrontend.java:1120)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1120)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/api/java/hadoop/mapred/HadoopInputFormat
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.hasMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:493)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.java.hadoop.mapred.HadoopInputFormat
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 17 more
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to make sure the jar you are submitting contains this dependency. The jar should be so called uber-jar (https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/start/dependencies.html#appendix-template-for-building-a-jar-with-dependencies)

Comment: which dependency do you refer Mr. Dawid Wysakowicz

Comment: The mongo one, that contains this class.

Comment: I am pretty sure you are not building a proper uber-jar. Please make sure you are using shade-plugin as described here: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.6/start/dependencies.html#appendix-template-for-building-a-jar-with-dependencies

Comment: I did follow the template.
here is my update pom.xml

Comment: remove the provided scope from mongo dependency. Provided means it will not be included in the uber-jar, thus needs to be present in the cluster.

Comment: i did remove scope provided from mongo dependency, still not working.
also remove scope provided from flink dependency, still not working too.

Comment: Hi, Could you figure out what was the issue? Even I'm facing the same problem. Please help if you could figure out @Nico

Comment: hi @bhargava ravali koganti, i'm still try to figure it.
i'll send here if any progress

Answer (score 0):

I added mongo-hadoop-core-2.0.2.jar in pom.xml and found the class in it.

[image]

Please try CNTR + SHIFT + T and check if that class is present in your classpath.

Comment: Could you please post your pom.xml file or .classpath file you are using?